# Deriving a polynomial with certain properties...

Tags: linear-algebra

What is an algebraic expression for a polynomial, $q$, with the following properties:
 1. $q$ has real coefficients.
 2. The only real zeros of $q$ are $-2$ with multiplicity $3$ and $1/4$ with multiplicity 2.
 3. A complex zero of $q$ is $i$ with multiplicity $1$.
 4. $q(0)=-5$.
Out of all polynomials with the above properties, there is exactly one with the smallest degree. What is the polynomial?

So we have $(x+2)^3$ and $(x-1/4)^2$ the pops up in $q$ but not sure what to do next. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Or would it be $(4x-1)^2$?

Comment: Since $x=i$ is a zero, then the conjugate zero theorem tells us that $x=-i$ is a zero too meaning we could have $q(x)=(x+2)^3(4x-1)^2(x^2+1)-3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us go point by point :

1. $q$ has real coefficients.
2. We can write $q(x) =(x+2)^3(x-1/4)^2p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is a product of polynomials with degree 2, up to a constant factor, and no real roots.
3. Thus $i$ is a root of $p$ with multiplicity $1$. By point 1, $-i$ is also a root with multiplicity $1$ : $p(x)=(x-i)(x+i)m(x)$ where $m$ is a product of polynomials with degree 2, no real roots and $m(i) \ne 0$. $(x-i)(x+i)=x^2+1$. Finally we have $q(x) = (x+2)^3(x-1/4)^2 (x^2+1) m(x)$.
4. $q(0)=5$, for this we just needs to adjust $m$.

The smallest degree polynomial $q$ satisfying all this is if we take $m(x) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. You just need to find its value by solving $q(0)=5$.